# What roars do Earplugs and HG Earplugs protect against?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

There are two levels of Hearing Skills, **Earplugs** and **HG Earplugs**, with HG Earplugs being able to block more momnster roars than Earplugs.

Which monster roars can be blocked with the Earplugs skill, and which roars can only be blocked with HG Earplugs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular earplugs: any large monster except the ones you need HG earplugs for.

HG earplugs: Gigginox, Diablos, Duramboros, Brachydios, Ceadeus, Jhen Moran, Alatreon, Dire Miralis, Abyssal Lagiacrus, Deviljho